# Looking for some SQL help I have a column that I want to pull from and cant create the select for it any advice would be helpful

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone help me figure out how to write a select statement that grabs the word after the @ symbol in a column like this any help would be appreciated I am using sql runner in looker the @ is attached to the word I just couldn't do that in the post

So I will never know how many words ill need to pull could be 1 or 50 and would potentially like the column to look like revjahwar,nhl ect... I made this union but still there may be a ton of @'s id have to pull out so its not too efficient

@ revjahwar #51&Done #21reasons #21dayswithPrime #IminmyPurpose #Purpose=Peace #iBelieve #Tiredofplayinggames #2019AintNobodyCare @ NFL

so far if you follow the comments there is a way to pull out the first one so far

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please provide a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake's `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function "Returns the substring that matches a regular expression within a string," which seems to be what you want to do here.  Here is an example.

```
with INSTAGRAM_POST_METRICS as (select $1 caption from values('@ revjahwar #51&Done #21reasons #21dayswithPrime #IminmyPurpose #Purpose=Peace #iBelieve #Tiredofplayinggames #2019AintNobodyCare @ NFL'))

select regexp_substr(
  caption,
  '@ ([^ ]+)',
  1,
  1,
  'e'
) word from INSTAGRAM_POST_METRICS;

word
revjahwar
```

Here is a way to get all of the @words

```
with INSTAGRAM_POST_METRICS as (select $1 caption from values('@ revjahwar #51&Done #21reasons #21dayswithPrime #IminmyPurpose #Purpose=Peace #iBelieve #Tiredofplayinggames #2019AintNobodyCare @ NFL'))

SELECT   array_to_string(array_agg(word), ',') word_list
FROM     (
                SELECT caption,
                       split_part(t.value, ' ', 2) word
                FROM   instagram_post_metrics,
                       lateral flatten(split(caption, '@')) t
                WHERE  t.value != '')
GROUP BY caption;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your quick response can I just have a little more context - so I tried running this which I know is obviously wrong now, just trying to add in the column name which is 'caption' and the table. Again thank you so much for the help



select regexp_substr(
  '@ revjahwar #51&Done #21reasons #21dayswithPrime #IminmyPurpose #Purpose=Peace #iBelieve #Tiredofplayinggames #2019AintNobodyCare @ NFL',
  '@ ([^ ]+)',
  1,
  1,
  'e'
) word
  from "CONVIVA_ANALYTICS"."INSTAGRAM_POST_METRICS" 
  where postid = '1971324349038518078_1547775030'

Comment: I updated the example to hopefully be more illustrative of how to use the regex_substr() function on a column instead of a constant.

Comment: Sorry to bother again on this - but there is more than one @ that I needed to pull out and I was wondering if there was a way to put it in a string. So I will never know how many words ill need to pull could be 1 or 50 and would potentially like the column to look like revjahwar,nhl ect...
I made this union but still there may be a ton of @'s id have to pull out so its not too efficient

Comment: select regexp_substr(
      caption,
      '@([^ ]+)',
      1,
      1,
      'e'
    ) word from "CONVIVA_ANALYTICS"."INSTAGRAM_POST_METRICS" where postid = '1971324349038518078_1547775030'  

UNION
        select regexp_substr(
      caption,
      '@([^ ]+)',
      1,
      2,
      'e'
    ) word from "CONVIVA_ANALYTICS"."INSTAGRAM_POST_METRICS" where postid = '1971324349038518078_1547775030'

Comment: I added a query that should do that.  When asking questions, it is helpful to provide both the input and output that you want.  That SQL is kind of gnarly, so a javascript UDF might be preferred to so something like [...str.matchAll(/(@ [^ ]+)/g)]

Comment: Nat - one last thing that works for having a space in @ I dont know how that was changed on the post but on the actual string its a twitter statement so there would be no space before the @

 '@revjahwar #51&Done #21reasons #21dayswithPrime #IminmyPurpose #Purpose=Peace #iBelieve #Tiredofplayinggames #2019AintNobodyCare @NFL'

Comment: Just pick the item from split_part() that contains the token you want.

Comment: Nat - I am really sorry to bother you again I am just kind of stuck on one thing and really would love your help, I know I asked this a while ago but one thing changed in the way we want to use this is there anyway for the outcome to still have the @ - before the word so the the outcome would be; @revjahwar,@nfl